# AWS Cognito Admin created user temp password verify & reset

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to verify an Admin created a user through password-reset-challenge using AWS Cognito generated a temporary password and I can't find the way or an example on how to use a temporary password and set new passwords for new users in javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Amazon Cognito developer guide provides an example of authenticating with a temporary password and handling the `newPasswordRequired` condition:

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: [...],
    onFailure: [...],
    mfaRequired: [...],
    newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
        // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new 
        // password and required attributes, if any, to complete 
        // authentication.

        // userAttributes: object, which is the user's current profile. It will list all attributes that are associated with the user. 
        // Required attributes according to schema, which don’t have any values yet, will have blank values.
        // requiredAttributes: list of attributes that must be set by the user along with new password to complete the sign-in.


        // Get these details and call 
        // newPassword: password that user has given
        // attributesData: object with key as attribute name and value that the user has given.
        cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, attributesData, this)
    }
});
```

Excerpted from the guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-admin-created-user.html

Note that the third argument to `completeNewPasswordChallenge` in the example is `this`, i.e., the object with the handler functions. This is because `completeNewPasswordChallenge` requires `onSuccess` and `onFailure` handlers, and you can often use the same handlers as you would for the `authenticateUser` result.

Comment: Please See my comment Below.

Answer (score 0):

I did go through the document you referred to. I do not understand what should be '`attributesData`'. Below is what I have done till now.

```
var authenticationData = {
       Username : email,
       Password : temppassword,
   };
   var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
   cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
       onSuccess: function (result) {
           console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
           console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);// User authentication was successful
       },

       onFailure: function(err) {
           alert(err);// User authentication was not successful
       },

       newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
           userAttributes: authenticationData; 
           requiredAttributes: email;
           var newPassword: password;
           // attributesData: object with key as attribute name and value that the user has given.
           cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, attributesData, this)
       }
   });
```

Comment: `attributesData` should be an object containing whatever attributes Cognito is missing for that user. The required attributes should be listed in the `requiredAttributes` parameter. It depends on how you create the original user.

For example, if you create the user without a `name`, but `name` is a required field, then you would need to need to set `attributesData` to something like `{ name: 'User Name' }`.